# Unity3D - Cant attach more then one body limb/mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to assemble together human from 3D model that have all limbs split. Like Head,Torso,Arms,Legs etc. And in runtime I would like to build a whole human with all those limbs assembled together. Here is what I do:

```
private void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Trying to build a Race!");
    RaceModelSO firstRace = _races[0];
    GameObject stiches = Instantiate(firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots()[0].mesh, new Vector3(773,0.83F,778), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    stiches.name = "HumanMale";
    for (int i = 0; i < firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots().Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            GameObject bodyPart = Instantiate(firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots()[i].mesh) as GameObject;
            _stitcher.Stitch(bodyPart, stiches);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the actual Stitcher class that is assembling the limbs together.

```
 public class Stitcher
    {

        public GameObject Stitch(GameObject sourceClothing, GameObject targetAvatar)
        {
            var boneCatalog = new TransformCatalog(targetAvatar.transform);
            var skinnedMeshRenderers = sourceClothing.GetComponentsInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
            var targetClothing = AddChild(sourceClothing, targetAvatar.transform);
 
 
            foreach (var sourceRenderer in skinnedMeshRenderers)
            {
                var targetRenderer = AddSkinnedMeshRenderer(sourceRenderer, targetClothing);
                targetRenderer.bones = TranslateTransforms(sourceRenderer.bones, boneCatalog);
            }
            return targetClothing;
        }
 
        private GameObject AddChild(GameObject source, Transform parent)
        {
            source.transform.parent = parent;
 
            foreach (Transform child in source.transform)
            {
                Object.Destroy(child.gameObject);
            }
 
            return source;
        }
 
        private SkinnedMeshRenderer AddSkinnedMeshRenderer(SkinnedMeshRenderer source, GameObject parent)
        {
            GameObject meshObject = new GameObject(source.name);
            meshObject.transform.parent = parent.transform;
 
            var target = meshObject.AddComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
            target.sharedMesh = source.sharedMesh;
            target.materials = source.materials;
            return target;
        }
 
        private Transform[] TranslateTransforms(Transform[] sources, TransformCatalog transformCatalog)
        {
            var targets = new Transform[sources.Length];
            for (var index = 0; index < sources.Length; index++)
                targets[index] = DictionaryExtensions.Find(transformCatalog, sources[index].name);
            return targets;
        }
 
        #region TransformCatalog
        private class TransformCatalog : Dictionary<string, Transform>
        {
            #region Constructors
            public TransformCatalog(Transform transform)
            {
                Catalog(transform);
            }
            #endregion
 
            #region Catalog
            private void Catalog(Transform transform)
            {
                if (ContainsKey(transform.name))
                {
                    Remove(transform.name);
                    Add(transform.name, transform);
                }
                else
                    Add(transform.name, transform);
                foreach (Transform child in transform)
                    Catalog(child);
            }
            #endregion
        }
        #endregion
 
 
        #region DictionaryExtensions
        private class DictionaryExtensions
        {
            public static TValue Find<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key)
            {
                TValue value;
                source.TryGetValue(key, out value);
                return value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
 
    }
```

So let me explain the issue. In `firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots()` I have all the prefabs with all limbs of the body. I get all of them and I call `_stitcher.Stitch()` for each of them.

The problem is that the first limb is the one created before the :

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots().Length; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        GameObject bodyPart = Instantiate(firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots()[i].mesh) as GameObject;
        _stitcher.Stitch(bodyPart, stiches);
    }
}
```

And that only the second limb gets attached properly all the others are there but not visible. Take a look:

[image]

So `SOH_HM_1_Head` is the first limb that was created before the `foreach` than is the second one `SOH_HM_1_Body` which is the first one inside the loop and only that one was created visible from all inside the foreach loop. All others are created but invisible. Take a look:

[image]

Do you have any idea why only the first limb from inside the foreach loop gets created visible? Any idea how can I solve this issue.

P.S.

Looks like the exact same issue was described here: [Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/stitch-multiple-body-parts-into-one-character.16485/page-3#post-3416493)

Can you suggest any other method rather than coroutine ?

Comment: That's a ton of code to sift through, but: since they're in the hierarchy, they are in the scene. If this were my project, I'd start by making sure they aren't just scaled down, out of the viewport or hidden inside the torso.

Comment: @3Dave they are all good in scale.

Comment: The `Transform` in your last screenshot shows `SOH_HM_1_Arms` centered at the origin with a scale of 1. Is that really what you expect (ie, what's correct for your model)?

Comment: @3Dave I've added P.S to my question. Please check the question again :)

Comment: Maybe checkout [UMA](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/uma-2-unity-multipurpose-avatar-35611) ;)

Comment: In general this sticher things sounds quite questionable if I only look at that `DictionaryExtensions.Find` method .. basically destroyes the complete purpose of `TryGetValue` ^^

Comment: @derHugo can you point out any other alternative that can do the same trick aka stitching parts in runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

For all people searching for a way to stitch many meshes into one all using same rig, I've come up with some small script: [Unity-3D-MeshStitcher](https://github.com/Armmegon/Unity-3D-MeshStitcher)